# Am I missing a trick to solving this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was playing around with a 3-D potential $V$ such that $V_{(r)} = 0$ for $r<a$, and $V_{(r)} = V_0$ otherwise. By using the Schrödinger Equation, I showed that: $$\frac{-\hbar}{2m}\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\bigl(  r^2\frac{d}{dr}\bigr)\psi = E\psi$$

I then used the substitution $\psi_{(r)}=f_{(r)}/r$ and $k=\sqrt{2mE}/\hbar$ to get: $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d^2f_{(r)}}{dr^2}=-\frac{k^2}{r}f_{(r)} \space\space\space\space\space(I)$$

which describes the wavefunction $\psi_{(r)}=f_{(r)}/r$ inside the sphere. Hence, the differential equation has the domain $0\leq r<a$, and I cannot multiply both sides by $r$. This is unfortunate, because there is a similar equation for the outside of the sphere: $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d^2f_{(r)}}{dr^2}=\frac{k'^2}{r}f_{(r)}$$
As this is outside the sphere, I can multiply both sides by $r$ to get a familiar differential equation that can be solved easily: $$\frac{d^2f_{(r)}}{dr^2}=k'^2f_{(r)}$$

If I do the same thing to $(I)$, I obtain the equation for simple harmonic motion, but substituting the solution back into $(I)$ as a sanity check gives a division by zero when evalutating for $r=0$. After that, I tried a number of substitutions to make $(I)$ have a more recognisable form - to no avail. Then I had the idea of multiplying my trial solution by some other function of $r$ so that upon substitution into $(I)$, the evaluation of $r=0$ doesn't give an infinity... but I don't know quite how to do that...

Long story short..... my question is: what trick do I need to get a meaningful solution to $(I)$?

Comment: Wikipedia has a discussion of the finite spherical well [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential#Sphere_with_square_potential) which may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's a good thing you asked this because the solution involves Bessel functions. You can take a look at the [full solution here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential#Sphere_with_square_potential). Don't forget that you need to match your wavefunction at any point of discontinuity (on the surface of the sphere) and you need regularity at the origin plus decay at infinity. This is why your solution will be Bessel functions of hte first kind.